# Unwanted delay in css3 animations triggered by adding classes

Tags: css, delay, css-animations

I am using the excellent css3 animations "library" provided by http://daneden.me/animate/

There is a slight but noticeable delay of about 1 second, when any of the examples are clicked. In the source it adds the animation-classes to the element and the browser will then execute the css animation statements.

I want the css3 animation to start immediately after clicking. Is there a solution?

Comment: can you provide an example to better help you.. when i use this library i dont get the delay.. so providing an example will help to see what your code looks like.. the site examples work fine.. what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have the property `animation-delay`, this property wait x seconds, then start the animation.

I see `animation-delay: .2s;` on `#animateTest`.

Maybe you have good eyes to see this little time.

Comment: Good hint but I already set this property to 0s, it still delays.